# Is this Time Series stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

[image: Time Series]

The adf test makes me think it is indeed stationary, since p<0.01, we can reject the null hypothesis and so it would be reasonable to think it is stationary, but that peak is kind of out of place for it to be stationary, isn't it?

```
adf.test(dades.ts)

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  dades.ts
Dickey-Fuller = -9.628, Lag order = 9, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dicker-Fulley test tests for a unit root that underlies your data. If this is the case, you will see a trend in your graph. This is clearly not the case in your graph. For me the peak just seems like a rare event or even noise.